# How to delete file permanently in dired

Tags: dired, files

The logical way should be C-u D to delete selected files permanently. How can we do that?

Comment: They are normally deleted permanently, do you maybe have `delete-by-moving-to-trash` set to `t`? If so, the way you suggest seems to be the way to go, at least the manual says so: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-File-Ops.html#Misc-File-Ops

Comment: @wvxvw: No, `C-u` (the way suggested by the OP) does not have that effect. (The manual page you cite does describe `delete-by-moving-to-trash`, however.)

Comment: @Drew it also says: "Supplying a prefix argument to M-x delete-file or M-x delete-directory makes them delete outright, instead of using the Trash, regardless of delete-by-moving-to-trash." I understand that `C-u` would supply prefix argument, but maybe you could try other ways of supplying the argument?

Comment: @wvxvw: Yes, but `D` is not bound to either of those commands. That's the point. `D` is bound (by default) to `dired-do-delete`. Like the other `dired-do-*` commands, a prefix arg for `dired-do-delete` is used numerically, to perform the action on the next *N* files.

Comment: @Drew ah... ok, I see now. Well, then this sounds like a sensible feature request (did you ever really needed to delete exactly four files, which also happened to be alphabetically next to each other?).

Comment: @wvxvw: I don't personally use arg *N* all that much, but I actually do think it is useful. You can and unmark files the same way. There are in fact lots of (32) `dired-do-*` commands, and they all work the same way. And there are another 39 [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus)  `diredp-do-*` commands that also act this way.

Comment: @wvxvw: And no, I don't think that `C-u D` (or `C-u d`) should have anything to do with whether or not the trash bin is used. And `D` already deletes (upon confirmation). And a Dired buffer can contain an arbitrary selection of files and directories. And even when it does not, the names can be sorted in a number of ways. So "the next N" files does not necessarily mean files in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Drew well, if you read the rationale for the behaviour of `delete-file`, you'd see it has its merits. It's a standard for desktop systems, and I think it would be nice if Dired played along.

Comment: @wvxvw: I have nothing against `delete-file`. Are you suggesting to change the default binding of `D` to `delete-file`? If so, please suggest it to `emacs-devel@gnu.org`. Doesn't do any good to suggest it to me. I think a better suggestion would be to bind it to some other key in `dired-mode-map`.

Comment: @wvxvw: FWIW, [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) has a command `diredp-delete-this-file`, which is bound to `C-k` and to the `delete` key (aka `<delete>`). I've just redefined it to use `delete-file` instead of `dired-do-delete`. HTH.

Comment: @Drew if OP won't do it then I will, sure, why not.

Answer (score 2):

`C-u D` deletes the next 4 files (or moves them to the trash bin, if `delete-by-moving-to-trash` is non-`nil`).

If you want to delete files permanently, then set `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to `nil`.  Then using `D` deletes the next *N* files (default 1), and `d` flags them for deletion by `x`.

Comment: Is there another way to temporarily delete selected file permanently? I think few people ever uses C-u D that way ( Do you count how many files to delete every time?), maybe replace the definition for D to do permanent delete with a prefix argument.

Comment: No idea what "*temporarily delete selected file permanently*" means. Temporarily? Permanently? `D`, with no prefix arg, deletes the file named on the current line: the prefix arg is implicitly `1`, so 1 file is deleted. Deletion is permanent or just a move to the trash bin according to option `delete-by-moving-to-trash`, as mentioned.

Comment: If some people use `C-u D` to override a non-`nil` value of `delete-by-moving-to-trash` and thus delete the file permanently, then they have bound `D` to a different command, or they have redefined or advised command `dired-do-delete`, the default binding of `D`.

Answer (score 0):

To follow-up from Drew's answer, I use the following function now:

```el
(defun dired-do-delete-skip-trash (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((delete-by-moving-to-trash nil))
    (dired-do-delete arg)))
```

I don't have this bound to a key, for safety reasons, but I can delete files skipping trash using <kbd>M-x</kbd> if absolutely needed.